# How to write a scripted field for nested fileds in Kibana(7.6)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm a newbie to Elasticsearch and Kibana and I want to write a scripted field to get the nested field value. I tried the following but it did not work.

> doc['dadatas.datas_name.keyword:pressure'].value

I want to get the pressure value for each doc (record).

> The output should be 12.56

My doc looks like this.

Thanks in advance!!

```
{
  "_index":"process_data",
  "_type":"_doc",
  "_id":"UzFHVDM1MTAxMTk5QSAyMDAyMDAwOTUzN19TVDNBMjBfU1QzQTIwMTAwXzIwMjAtMDItMThUMTk6NDc6MzM=",
  "_version":1,
  "_score":1,
  "_source":{
    "eid":"",
    "line":"Line 1",
    "equipment":"Equipment 1",
    "ladderver":"",
    "registrydate":"2020-02-18T19:47:33",
    "registryutcdate":"2020-02-18T10:47:33",
    "setupid":"",
    "workid":"2345743",
    "datas":[
      {
        "datas_id":"001",
        "name":"cycletime",
        "value":"13.9"
      },
      {
        "datas_id":"002",
        "name":"machinetime",
        "value":"10.7"
      },
      {
        "datas_id":"003",
        "name":"pressure",
        "value":"12.56"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "pressure": {
      "script": {
        "source": "for(item in params._source.datas){ if(item.name=='pressure')return item.value;} return '';"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Script fields are calculated on fly. So better option would be to extract  field from inner_hits

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "datas",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "datas.name.keyword": {
            "value": "pressure"
          }
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index5",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "kf6xw3EB8jeMa7x6RMwZ",
        "_score" : 0.9808291,
        "_source" : {
          "eid" : "",
          "line" : "Line 1",
          "equipment" : "Equipment 1",
          "ladderver" : "",
          "registrydate" : "2020-02-18T19:47:33",
          "registryutcdate" : "2020-02-18T10:47:33",
          "setupid" : "",
          "workid" : "2345743",
          "datas" : [
            {
              "datas_id" : "001",
              "name" : "cycletime",
              "value" : "13.9"
            },
            {
              "datas_id" : "002",
              "name" : "machinetime",
              "value" : "10.7"
            },
            {
              "datas_id" : "003",
              "name" : "pressure",
              "value" : "12.56"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "datas" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 0.9808291,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index5",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "kf6xw3EB8jeMa7x6RMwZ",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "datas",
                    "offset" : 2
                  },
                  "_score" : 0.9808291,
                  "_source" : {
                    "datas_id" : "003",
                    "name" : "pressure",
                    "value" : "12.56"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

EDIT 1: 
My answer was for query in dev tools
For Index pattern script field , you need to add below

```
for(item in params._source.datas)
{
    if(item.name=='pressure'){
      return item.value;
   }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.
I tried it in scripted filed, but it didn't work for me.
Any idea? I really appreciate your help.

I have uploaded the error screenshot. Please check it.

Comment: @ jaspreet chahal
I have selected the index pattern and created a scripted field.

Comment: Glad could be of help :)